# Typescript: How to define interface for dynamical object like this

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have function which takes this object as one of the arguments:

```
{
    section: "main",
    sectionColor: "#0072c6",
    favIcon: "default",
    libraries: {
        value: "librariesFiles",
        type: "jsIncludes"
    },
    components: {
        value: "comoponentFiles",
        type: "jsIncludes"
    }
}
```

Here is interface I came up to define this property in function:

```
interface IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem {
    value: string;

    type: string;
}

export interface IgenerateFileArgument {
    [key: string]: (string | IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem);
}
```

Shortly, I'm trying define object with dynamic number of properties which can be equal either to string value either to another object with two properties...

But compiler is complaining, and I think issue is in this line:
(string | IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem)

Is there any obvious mistake or am I trying to do impossible thing?

[image: I'm getting error here]

[image: And the error]

Comment: What are `librariesFiles` and `comoponentFiles` are they strings?

Comment: What exactly is the compiler complaining about? It compiles for me without errors.

Comment: Nitzan, yes those are strings. I have updated question with some screenshots

Comment: Screenshots are not as good as text/code, plus from the looks of it, it seems that no, `librariesFiles` and `comoponentFiles` are not strings, they are `string[]`, am I right? Are there any more things that you can add/fix about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the following example, you can view it here in the TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IgenerateFileArgument%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(string%20%7C%20IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20p%3A%20string%20%3D%20'uo'%0D%0Avar%20lol%20%3Astring%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B'no'%2C%20'po'%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fix%20this%20to%20string%20type%0D%0Avar%20a%3A%20IgenerateFileArgument%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09value%3A%20p%2C%0D%0A%09%09type%3A'mo'%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09b%3A'lol'%2C%0D%0A%09e%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09value%3A'yo'%2C%0D%0A%09%09type%3A'mo'%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%09m%3A%20%7B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20you%20can%20also%20remove%20this%20instead%0D%0A%09%09value%3Alol%2C%20%0D%0A%09%09type%3A'go'%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D). I was able to reconstruct you're issue. It seems that either one (or all) of the following librariesFiles, componentFiles, modellingContentStates, sharePointStates is of type string[].

```
interface IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem {
    value: string;

    type: string;
}

export interface IgenerateFileArgument {
    [key: string]: (string | IgenerateFileArgumentObjectItem);
}

var p: string = 'uo'
var lol :string[] = ['no', 'po']; // Fix this to string type
var a: IgenerateFileArgument = {
    c: {
        value: p,
        type:'mo'
    },
    b:'lol',
    e: {
        value:'yo',
        type:'mo'
    },
    m: {  // you can remove this instead
        value:lol,
        type:'go'
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you, silly me missed something. Also when working between different types, good thing to know about type casting